# Let a > 0 be rational. Prove that if a^a is rational, then a is an integer.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm struggling with this question from Laczkovich and Sos.

*Let $a > 0$ be rational. Prove that if $a^a$ is rational, then $a$ is an integer.*

I know that if $n$, $k$ are positive natural numbers, then $\sqrt[k]{n}$ is either an integer or irrational. This is proven in an earlier question, and I think that the book wants us to use that fact in our proof for this exercise.

So far I have

$$ a = \frac{m}{n} \\
a^a = \frac{p}{q} \\
a = \frac{\sqrt[m]{p^n}}{\sqrt[m]{q^n}}
$$

Now $m$, $n$, $p$ and $q$ are all positive integers, so $\sqrt[m]{p^n}$ and $\sqrt[m]{q^n}$ are either integers or irrational. I'm guessing that the proof proceeds based on certain properties of irrational numbers or integers to show that $\sqrt[m]{q^n} = 1 \Leftrightarrow q = 1$ and thus $a \in N^+$, but I can't see how to get there. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=\frac{m}{n}$ where $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $a^a = r\in\mathbb Q$, then $a^m = r^n$.

If $n\not=\pm 1$, take a prime factor $p$ of $n$, consider the $p$-adic valuation $v_p$, we have $$v_p(a) = - v_p(n)\not=0$$ $$v_p(a^m) = v_p(r^n)\Rightarrow m v_p(a) = nv_p(r)$$

And $$n | m v_p(a) \Rightarrow n|v_p(a) \Rightarrow n|v_p(n) \Rightarrow n\le v_p(n)$$

But $$n\ge p^{v_p(n)}\ge 2^{v_p(n)}>v_p(n)$$

Comment: This might be right, but I’m looking for something I can understand (i.e. something more elementary). I should have made that more clear in the question.

Comment: $p$-adic valuations for rational numbers is completely elementary. It's just a slightly fancier way to use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. You can replace $v_p(n)$ by "the exponent of $p$ in the factorization of $n$".